Probability of two dice being 6 is 1/36. Is that statistically significant for $\alpha = .05$?
In one sample t-test, when the sample mean is too extreme, we say that this is statistically significant.
Although the pair of dice example does not satisfy the assumptions of the one sample t-test, we can say the following:

$P(\text{sample mean} \geq 5) = \frac{4}{36}$
$P(\text{sample mean} \geq 6) = \frac{1}{36}$

Let's set $\alpha = .05$.
For the first case, the dice seem to be fair, because the likelihood of obtaining such extreme sample mean is $\geq .05$.
For the second case, should we say that the dice are unfair?
I must be missing something because this is somewhat similar to obtaining 21 in a 21 sided fair die, which should not directly indicate that the die in unfair.

I cannot make sense of this question, because you aren't testing any data: you are attempting to connect probability statements about known, definite random variables to t-testing.  Maybe I'm missing something about how you characterize the "first case" and "second case:" could you explain?

What has a distribution with $P(\text{sample mean} \geq 5) = \frac{4}{36}$
and $P(\text{sample mean} \geq 6) = \frac{1}{36}$, and how is that related to the sample mean?

Speak of the sum of two times throwing the same die. If it is a fair die, you would expect a sum of 7. You seem to be willing to reject the null hypothesis only for a sum of 12, not for a sum of 2. Why?

Why do you say that a sum of 12 means rejection but a sum of 2 does not?

Are you asking me @Dave or the OP?

@BenP I thought you were the OP, and it seems we have the same question to the OP.

Okay @Dave, already thought so.

If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems you have discovered how important the definitions of your null hypothesis and test statistic are, along with a "flaw" in the hypothesis testing framework.
Denote your null hypothesis $H_0$ and your alternative hypothesis $H_1$. Let's say you want $H_0$ to be "die is fair," i.e., one roll follows a discrete uniform distribution on the interval $[1, 6]$. Then you define $H_1 = H_0^\complement$, i.e. "die is not fair." In this case, the sample mean is a poor test statistic. If you rolled the die 60 times, rolling 10 of each number vs. 30 1's and 30 6's would result in the same test statistic (thus same p-value), but should probably lead to significantly different conclusions about whether or not the die is fair.
If instead your $H_0$ is that the expected value of each roll is 3.5, then now it makes sense to use sample mean as a test statistic. It seems based on your question that you want a one-sided test, i.e., $H_1$ is that expected value is greater than 3.5.
In this second case, yes, if we rolled the same die twice and got a 6 each time, we would calculate the p-value as $P(\text{sample mean} \geq 6 \mid H_0)$, which is $\frac{1}{36}$. So in this case, we would reject the null hypothesis, concluding that the die is unfair.

I must be missing something because this is somewhat similar to obtaining 21 in a 21 sided fair die, which should not directly indicate that the die in unfair.

You're right! Assuming this 21-sided die is in fact fair (but you have no way of knowing this), you should still reject the null hypothesis, but this would be a false positive. In fact, when you are choosing your $\alpha$ threshold, you are choosing your expected false positive rate. That is, any given test where the null hypothesis is actually true has an $\alpha$ chance of being rejected (incorrectly).

I understand your nice first case explanation. But it is difficult to understand the difference between your first and second case. In the second case, you also assume that under H0 the uniform distribution holds, and I understood from what you explained before (first case) that the sample mean is not a good test statistic then.

This is an excellent point. The difference lies in the exact formulation of the alternate hypotheses (which I wasn't clear about). In first example, the alternate hypothesis is that the die could be any distribution other than Uniform(1,6). The calculations in the second example would really only make sense if the alternate was that the die could follow any distribution that is Uniform(1+x, 6+x). But obviously you can look at the die and see that this is not possible. I'll revise my answer accordingly

After thinking about this some more, I think I got a little bit off-topic in my above comment. In either case, you can have your null be that the die is Uniform(1,6). What makes the difference is your alternate hypothesis. If your alternate hypothesis is "any other distribution on the integers 1-6," then sample mean is bad. If your alternate hypothesis is "some other distribution on 1-6 that has a different mean," then the sample mean makes sense.

Thanks for the extra explanation. I'm still doubting however. With the test as you propose it, if the p-value is smaller than some alpha, one could conclude that the null hypothesis "die is fair" is not supported. Okay so far. But If the p-value is larger than alpha, e.g. p=21/36 for mean=3.5, this does not necessarily support the null hypothesis "the die is fair". So such a test would only be meaningful if you already know that the die you may have is either fair, or unfair in such a way that the mean is not 3.5. E.g. all dice with a symmetrical distribution on 1-6 are excluded already.

And I guess that is what you meant to say in your last comment. Now I understand it I hope. It's a quite "extraordinary" situation. Thanks!

"So such a test would only be meaningful if you already know that the die you may have is either fair, or unfair in such a way that the mean is not 3.5."
Yes, you put it much better than I. Glad to help

Three comments:
For your first example, looking at only two dice: Having each die land on 6 is no more unlikely or unusual than having both land on 5. Or 4. Or...  So the basic setup of your question doesn't really make sense.
A statistical test cannot possibly tell you whether or not a pair of dice are fair or not. If you set up the test properly, it could tell you that the results would be quite unlikely if the dice were fair. How you interpret that depends. Is this part of a magic show? If so, it seems pretty likely the dice are not fair (or the way of tabulating the results is rigged). If these are new dice, not gimmicked, you'be more likely to conclude that the unusual results are simply a matter of chance. Context always matters. A p-value can only tell you how rare the results would be if a null hypothesis (and a bunch of assumptions) are true.
In your last example you assume a fair 21-sided die. Once you assume the die is fair, why would you test whether it is unfair?
